# Recorrer JSON para insertar en base de datos SQLite de Android

Tags: android, android-studio, json, android-sqlite

estoy recibiendo un JSON de un servidor con la estructura que se puede apreciar en el siguiente codigo...

```
{
 "actividades": [
 {
  "1": {
    "actividad": "Pioneros",
    "tipo": "1",
    "dia": "2017-10-25",
    "hora_inicio": "10:00:00",
    "hora_fin": "12:00:00",
    "ubicacion": "fgf",
    "expositor": "Alex",
    "biografia": "",
    "descripcion": "",
    "edificio": "1"
  },
  "2": {
    "actividad": "Pioneros",
    "tipo": "1",
    "dia": "2017-10-25",
    "hora_inicio": "10:00:00",
    "hora_fin": "12:00:00",
    "ubicacion": "fgf",
    "expositor": "Alex",
    "biografia": "",
    "descripcion": "",
    "edificio": "1"
  },
  "3": {
    "actividad": "Pioneros",
    "tipo": "1",
    "dia": "2017-10-25",
    "hora_inicio": "10:00:00",
    "hora_fin": "12:00:00",
    "ubicacion": "fgf",
    "expositor": "Alex",
    "biografia": "",
    "descripcion": "",
    "edificio": "1"
     }
   }
  ]
}
```

Usando la herramienta Online JSON Viewer pude notar que se agrega otro JSON Object 0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, como puedo insertarlo en la base de datos local de Android que es SQLite, intente de la siguiente forma (codigo de Android Studio)...

```
try {
                url = new URL(cadena);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", params[2]);

                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine = "";
                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }

                    String finalJSON = response.toString();
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(finalJSON);

                    JSONArray parentArray = respuestaJSON.getJSONArray("actividades");
                    db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
                    for (int i = 1; i < parentArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Integer idEvento = i;
                        String Descripcion = finalObject.getString("descripcion");
                        String Horafin = finalObject.getString("hora_fin");
                        String Ubicacion = finalObject.getString("ubicacion");
                        String Actividad = finalObject.getString("actividad");
                        String Biografia = finalObject.getString("biografia");
                        String Expositor = finalObject.getString("expositor");
                        String horaInicio = finalObject.getString("hora_inicio");
                        String Dia = finalObject.getString("dia");
                        String Edificio = finalObject.getString("edificio");
                        String Tipo = finalObject.getString("tipo");
                        Integer TipoIn = Integer.valueOf(Tipo);

                        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                        contentValues.put("idEvento", idEvento);
                        contentValues.put("Actividad", Actividad);
                        contentValues.put("Dia", Dia);
                        contentValues.put("horaInicio", horaInicio);
                        contentValues.put("horaFin", Horafin);
                        contentValues.put("Ubicacion", Ubicacion);
                        contentValues.put("Descripcion", Descripcion);
                        contentValues.put("Biografia", Biografia);
                        contentValues.put("Expositor", Expositor);
                        contentValues.put("Tipo", TipoIn.toString());
                        contentValues.put("Edificio", Edificio);

                        if (TipoIn == 1){
                            db.insert("Aqui", null, contentValues);
                        }else if (TipoIn == 2) {
                            db.insert("Aqui", null, contentValues);
                        }else if (TipoIn == 3){
                            db.insert("Aqui", null, contentValues);
                        }else if (TipoIn == 4){
                            db.insert("Aqui", null, contentValues);
                        }
                    }
                    if (db.isOpen()){
                        db.close();
                    }
                    in.close();
                }
                con.disconnect();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Pero al parecer me falta ingresar al Objeto JSON '0', alguien podría instruirme el como hacerlo o que debería hacer, gracias.

Comment: Hola Victor, podrías poner el código, no tomar pantallazo por favor.

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta, además agrega también el error que se obtiene.

Comment: Listo ya lo añadí, el error es que simplemente no lo añade los campos del JSON a la base de datos, creo es por que me falta decirle que debe entrar al JSON Object denominado 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu `JSONArray` lleva un  `JSONObject` y este lleva dentro los pares, puede obtener los datos asi:

```
JSONArray parentArray = respuestaJSON.getJSONArray("actividades");
JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject json = finalObject.getJSONObject("1");
String descripcion = json.getString("descripcion");
```

tu JSONArraylleva una sola posicion, en caso que sepas que llevas mas debes usar uns for para recorrerlo.

Comment: Perfecto te agradezco mucha la ayuda, funciono, realmente gracias.

Comment: que bueno! saludos!